# R: Combining four variables into one

Tags: r, if-statement, variables

I have 4 variables (races, asian_news,black_news,nhpi_news, and latino_news).

'races' is a factor with 6 levels: White, Asians, NHPI, Black, Latino, Multiracial.

'asian_news','black_news','nhpi_news', and 'latino_news' are a series of survey questions that have 4 outcomes: [1] ethnic, [2] mainstream, [3] both, and [4] DK.

These questions ask respondents if they primarily get their news through ethnic sources or through U.S mainstream media. These survey questions operate as follows:

- only the Asian-Americans group are asked asian_news
- only NHPI are asked nhpi_news
- only Latinos are asked latino_news
- only Blacks are asked black_news

The replication data can be downloaded here:

```
library(foreign)
pre<-read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzitbwr6q2i26gt/sampledata.csv?dl=1")
```

As of now, the cross-tab between races and asian_news look like this:

```
 > with(pre,table(races,asian_news,useNA="always"))
                                   asian_news
races                           ethnic mainstream both  DK <NA>
  3. WHITES                          0          0    0   0  500
  1. ASIAN AMERICANS               770        863  294  41  142
  2. PACIFIC ISLANDERS               0          0    0   0  410
  4.BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS      0          0    0   0  520
  6. latinos                         0          0    0   0  514
  9. MULTIRACIAL AMERICANS           0          0    0   0    0
  <NA>                               0          0    0   0    0
```

Similarly, the cross-tab between races and black_news look like this:

```
> with(pre,table(races,black_news,useNA="always"))
                               black_news
races                           ethnic mainstream both   DK <NA>
  3. WHITES                          0          0    0    0  500
  1. ASIAN AMERICANS                 0          0    0    0 2110
  2. PACIFIC ISLANDERS               0          0    0    0  410
  4.BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS     53        366   67   12   22
  6. latinos                         0          0    0    0  514
  9. MULTIRACIAL AMERICANS           0          0    0    0    0
  <NA>                               0          0    0    0    0
```

One could generate similar crosstabs with the following codes:

```
with(pre,table(races,latino_news,useNA="always"))
with(pre,table(races,nhpi_news,useNA="always"))
```

I want to combine these four survey questions to one unified variable. Ideally, the crosstabs between races and the desired variable would look like this

```
> with(pre,table(races,desired_variable,useNA="always"))
                               desired_variable
races                           ethnic mainstream both   DK <NA>
  3. WHITES                          0        500    0    0    0
  1. ASIAN AMERICANS               770        863  294   41  142
  2. PACIFIC ISLANDERS              22        332   24   13   19
  4.BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS     53        366   67   12   22
  6. latinos                       142        302   47    1   22 
  9. MULTIRACIAL AMERICANS           0          0    0    0    0
  <NA>                               0          0    0    0    0
```

How do I generate the "desired_variable" variable? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This `tidyr` & `magrittr` solution might work for:

```r
pre<-read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzitbwr6q2i26gt/sampledata.csv?dl=1")

library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

pre %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains('news'), names_to = 'ethnicNews') %$%
  table(races, value,useNA = 'always')
#>                                 value
#> races                            both   DK ethnic mainstream <NA>
#>   1. ASIAN AMERICANS              324   53    825       1401 8545
#>   2. PACIFIC ISLANDERS             24   13     22        332 1249
#>   3. WHITES                         0    0      0          0 2004
#>   4. BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS   36    5     24        163  716
#>   5. BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS   31    7     29        203  866
#>   6. latinos                       47    1    142        302 1564
#>   9. MULTIRACIAL AMERICANS          0    0      0          0  220
#>   <NA>                              0    0      0          0    0
```

And using `recode` from `dplyr`, you could remove that unnecessary double entry:

```r
pre<-read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzitbwr6q2i26gt/sampledata.csv?dl=1")

library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

pre %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains('news'), names_to = 'ethnicNews') %>% 
  mutate(races = recode(races,'5. BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS' = '4. BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS')) %$%
  table(races, value,useNA = 'always')
#>                                 value
#> races                            both   DK ethnic mainstream <NA>
#>   1. ASIAN AMERICANS              324   53    825       1401 8545
#>   2. PACIFIC ISLANDERS             24   13     22        332 1249
#>   3. WHITES                         0    0      0          0 2004
#>   4. BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS   67   12     53        366 1582
#>   6. latinos                       47    1    142        302 1564
#>   9. MULTIRACIAL AMERICANS          0    0      0          0  220
#>   <NA>                              0    0      0          0    0
```